# jQuery works between <script> tags but not in a .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble to understand why following code is working between script-tages in a html file, but not in a js-file.

**I have refereced my javascript file as followed and imported jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./../js/app.js"></script>
```

**This is working**

```
<html>
...

<script>
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $.each($("#consumerDetails tbody tr"), function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) === -1)
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Everything works fine in app.js, exept the just mentioned code. But if I put it between the script tags, in my html code, it works?!

Why does my code works between the script tags but not in my javascript file app.js?

Console with f12 is not showing any errors.

Comment: Can you show us how it looks in the app.js file?

Comment: _Where_ in your HTML file are you placing the references?

Comment: Show us the app.js absolute url plz

Comment: Replace `src="./../js/app.js"` with `src="../../js/app.js"`

Comment: Also it looks like in your second block you are putting it right before the </html>, which makes me think this is a document ready issue.

Comment: Have you tried putting your code inside `$( document ).ready(function() { ... })`?

Comment: Either the script is not loading the external file or you are placing the scripts at different location. Impossible for us to know.

Comment: I agree about document ready. To troubleshoot, include `console.log($('#search').length);` and see what it outputs to your browser console.

Comment: @Twometer src path works, because all my other javascript works fine!

Comment: @palaѕн How would "document ready" look like? The main question is why is this code working between the tags and not in the js-file?

Comment: It's not working in the js file because you load the js file in the head and when it gets executed, $('#search') does not exist.  Document.ready delays the execution until the elements on the page do exist.

Comment: See [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function)

Comment: @showdev `console.log($('#search').length);` returns 1 if I put the code between script tags and 0 if I put the code in js-file.

Comment: Or, you could include your app.js include right before the </body> and forgo the document ready

Comment: Yes, jQuery offers a convenient shorthand to run your code on document.ready. `$(function() { /** your code here */ })`

Comment: Also see [why javascript runs when at bottom of page or sometimes from top of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228495/why-javascript-runs-when-at-bottom-of-page-or-sometimes-from-top-of-page)

Comment: Thanks guys! Including the app.js at the end seems to work like @Taplar mentions