# JQuery slider exploding out on page load

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I've been trying to figure out how to stop this slider on a site I'm working on: [link omitted] from loading while the page is loading and pushing all the content down.

I have tried to implement Jerph's answer as in this post: [Hide jQuery Accordion while loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703783/hide-jquery-accordion-while-loading) but unsuccessfully can anyone shed some light on this issue and tell my what I'm doing wrong.

The Slider is initiated by:

```
 $('#slider .items').cycle({
  fx: 'blindY',
  timeout: 9599
 });
```

As in Jerphs answer:

```
<body <?php echo $bodyid;?>>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery('body').addClass('js');</script>
```

I have put the body.js infront of the slider styles in the main stylesheet.

```
  body.js #slider  {margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:-60px}
  body.js #slider  .items {height: 283px; width:990px; position:relative;}
  body.js #slider  .items div {height:212px; width:990px; padding-top: 72px; background: 0px 72px no-repeat url("../images/banners/banner-bg.png"); background-color:transparent !important;}
  body.js #slider  .items div h1 {float: left; font-size:30px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; margin:20px 0 0 20px;}
  body.js #slider  .items div p {float: left; font-size:20px; color:#C5E9FF; font-weight:bold; margin: 10px 0 0 20px; line-height:23px;}
  body.js #slider  .items div img {float: right; position:relative;}

  body.js #slider  .items .item-1 img {right:-1px; top:-23px; height:233px;}
  body.js #slider  .items .item-1 p, #banner .items .item-1 p {width:530px;}

  body.js #slider  .items .item-2 img {right:50px; top:-71px; height:281px;}
  body.js #slider  .items .item-2 p, #banner .items .item-2 p {width:530px;}

  body.js #slider  .items .item-3 img {right:50px; top:-32px; height:242px;}
  body.js #slider  .items .item-3 p, #banner .items .item-3 p {width:530px;}

  body.js #slider  .items .item-4 img {right:50px; top:-62px; height:272px;}
  body.js #slider  .items .item-4 p, #banner .items .item-4 p {width:550px;}

  body.js #slider  .banner-signup { position:relative; top:-20px; left:-20px; margin:20px 0 0; display:block; float:right; width:100px; height:41px; background: top left no-repeat url(../images/banners/sign-up.png);}
  body.js #slider  .banner-tour { position:relative; top:-20px; left:-20px; margin:20px 15px 0 0; display:block; float:right; width:73px; height:43px; background: top left no-repeat url(../images/banners/tour.png);}

  body.js #slider  .items .item-1 p a.banner-signup { position:relative; top:5px; left:-20px; margin:20px 0 0; display:block; float:right; width:100px; height:41px; background: top left no-repeat url(../images/banners/sign-up.png);}
  body.js #slider  .items .item-1 p a.banner-tour { position:relative; top:5px; left:-20px; margin:20px 15px 0 0; display:block; float:right; width:73px; height:43px; background: top left no-repeat url(../images/banners/tour.png);}

  body.js #slider  .items .item-3 p a.banner-signup { position:relative; top:-27px; left:-43px; margin:20px 0 0; display:block; float:right; width:100px; height:41px; background: top left no-repeat url(../images/banners/sign-up.png);}
  body.js #slider  .items .item-3 p a.banner-tour { position:relative; top:-27px; left:-43px; margin:20px 15px 0 0; display:block; float:right; width:73px; height:43px; background: top left no-repeat url(../images/banners/tour.png);}
```

Is there a way that I can stop having this slider exploding out?

Comment: your linked example requires authentication..? Also, please don't hide URLs behind [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/) (or similar) links; please use the full **real** URL (I like to see where I'm going when I click a link, blame too many years of Slashdot for that...).

Comment: The username and password is 'list' without comments.

Comment: The reason why I use tinyURL is so the address doesn't appear in search engines. I apologise for any inconvenience.

Comment: All links are `rel="nofollow"`-ed, so it's not an issue (unless the search spiders ignore the `"nofollow"` directive).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do here is just hide the slider with a `.hidden` class with `display:none` until `jQuery.ready(…)` gets trigger, and make the slider visible after its get initialized.

Comment: I still can't get this to work, it is still exploding out onto the page and slowing down the load page. Both the slider and the accordions are doing it.

Comment: I don't think this would be the right thing todo, I'm trying to find the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the slider exploding is the php include statements I'm using around 20 currently. I omit these and the slider loads up perfectly.